# Make div work like a check box

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of color names with check boxes. Instead of having the check boxes be there, I would like to be able to select the entire div with the title in it. Checked div's would be understood with a different background color.

my html is also and erb file and contains ruby. I want the <%= color.name %> to be inside the "idea[color_ids][]" id div. but when I try putting them inside each other I get a rails error

html/erb file

```
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
        <% for color in Color.master_colors %>
            <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[color_ids][]", color.id,   
@idea.colors.include?(color) %> <%= color.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

how can I get color.names inside the "idea[color_ids][]" div instead of just inside the li div? so that I can select the entire "idea[color_ids][]" (with color name title inside)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<label for="check1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check1" /> Testing
</label>
```

Then you could either treat the label like a div or add a div-wrapper inside label.

Comment: the thing is that I have ruby modles that create these tags in my original file and I do not know how to put the color.name inside the idea_color_ids_ div with ruby

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to custom style your checkbox.

1. Hide the checkbox:

   ```
   .multi-column-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
       visibility: hidden;
   }
   ```
2. Add css styles (css class) to your 'li' say 'column-checkbox'

   ```
    .column-checkbox{
        width: .. px;
        height: .. px;
        background-color: some_color;
        borders...
        **position: relative;**
    }
   ```
3. Add styles to your checkbox label

   ```
   .column-checkbox label {
       **position: absolute;**
       /* top, bottom, left, right */ 
       width: ...;
       height: ...;
       /* etc */
   }
   ```
4. Style your label for after checkbox is selected

   ```
   .column-checkbox label:after {
       /* Styles after select */
   }
   ```

You can also add styles for hover on the list item

```
.column-checkbox label:hover{
    /* Hover styles */
}
```

You can probably find examples on the net for custom css checkbox. Also, take a look at this answer: [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css/4148544#4148544)